# GnuCobol calling C function with argument of type double

Tags: c, cobol, gnucobol

I have C two functions doing exactly the same thing. The only difference is their return type and first argument type:

```c
int func1(int a, int *b) {
    if (a > 0) {
        *b = 0;
        return 1;
    }

    *b = -1;
    return 0;
}

double func2(double a, int *b) {
    if (a > (double)0.0) {
        *b = 0;
        return 1.0;
    }

    *b = -1;
    return (double)0.0;
}
```

Compiling them to the library:

```bash
gcc -c -static -o testlib.o testlib.c
```

The following COBOL code calls both functions:

```
       IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
       PROGRAM-ID. CallCFunctions.
       
       ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.

       DATA DIVISION.
       WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
       01  VAR-AI USAGE BINARY-SHORT SIGNED.
       01  VAR-BI USAGE BINARY-SHORT SIGNED.
       01  VAR-CI USAGE BINARY-SHORT SIGNED.
       
       01  VAR-AD USAGE BINARY-DOUBLE.
       01  VAR-BD USAGE BINARY-DOUBLE.
       01  VAR-CD USAGE BINARY-DOUBLE.
       

       PROCEDURE DIVISION.
           
           MOVE 1 TO VAR-AI.
           MOVE -10 TO VAR-BI.
           MOVE ZERO TO VAR-CI.
           CALL "func1" USING BY VALUE VAR-AI BY REFERENCE VAR-BI
               RETURNING VAR-CI
           DISPLAY "Calling 'func1'".
           DISPLAY "A = ", VAR-AI, " B = ", VAR-BI, " C = ", VAR-CI

           MOVE 1 TO VAR-AD.
           MOVE -10 TO VAR-BD.
           MOVE ZERO TO VAR-CD.
           CALL "func2" USING BY VALUE VAR-AD BY REFERENCE VAR-BD
               RETURNING VAR-CD
           DISPLAY "Calling 'func2'".
           DISPLAY "A = ", VAR-AD, " B = ", VAR-BD, " C = ", VAR-CD


       STOP RUN.
```

Compiling COBOL code:

```bash
cobc -x -free -o test test.cbl testlib.o
```

The first function works but the second generates an error:

> attempt to reference unallocated memory (signal SIGSEGV)
> Full output

```
Calling 'func1'
A = +00001 B = +00000 C = +00001
Calling 'func2'

attempt to reference unallocated memory (signal SIGSEGV)
```

Could anyone explain what seems to be the problem?

Comment: Compiling with `-Wall` will say `BY VALUE is unfinished` so you seem to trigger an edge case.

To get more output: please compile with `cobc -gx -free -o test -static test.cbl testlib.c`, then rerun with `gdb ./test` and share its output in your question.

Comment: Possibly relevant: What version of GnuCOBOL do you use on which environment?

Comment: @AdrianMole thanks for that.
it works with FLOAT-LONG.

Comment: If you do compile all those functions together - as suggested above - you do get compile/link warnings/errors, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your declared variable types (`USAGE`) in the COBOL source are not compatible with those in the C source.

First, the `BINARY-DOUBLE` type in GnuCobol is a 64-bit, native **integer**. From the [GnuCOBOL Programmer’s Guide](https://gnucobol.sourceforge.io/HTML/gnucobpg.html#USAGE):

> BINARY-DOUBLE [ SIGNED ]
>  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>  
>         Range of Values:  -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 –
> 9,223,372,036,854,775,807
>         Storage Format:   Native Binary Integer

What you want, if you're after the IEEE-754 64-bit floating point type (as is the C `double`) is `FLOAT-LONG`. From the same document:

> FLOAT-LONG
>  ~~~~~~~~~~
>  
>         Range of Values:  Approx.
> -1.797693134862316 * 10<sup>308</sup> – 1.797693134862316 * 10<sup>308</sup>
>         Storage Format:   Native IEEE 754 Binary64 Floating-point

However, I can't see that this – of itself – would cause the reported `SIGSEGV` error, as both memory 'units' have the same size (although the passed `a` value will be interpreted as a nonsense `double`).

What's more likely causing that memory violation is that the type of the `int` arguments are also wrong: `BINARY-SHORT` is a **16 bit** integer but the C `int` is **32 bits** (see the same, linked document).

You need to:

1. Either use the `BINARY-LONG` (or `BINARY-INT`) type in your COBOL code;
2. Or use the `short` type for your arguments and return type in your C code.

As it stands, your C functions are writing (or *attempting* to write) 32 bits to a location that's only guaranteed to be 16 bits in size; this is **undefined behaviour** and is more likely the cause of the error. [You're just (un)lucky that, in the `func1` call, that UB didn't trigger the memory violation!]

Answer (score 0):

I've been out of Cobol for 23 years, and only understand the VERY basics of C at this point...but you didn't define that VAR-BD was a signed integer in your COBOL code -

and tried to assign a negative number. (MOVE -10 TO VAR-BD.) In the old days, that would have caused a problem in storage eventually.

Comment: Actually, the `BINARY-DOUBLE` type *is* a signed integer (see my answer).